# UVM Register Model: volatile register value change

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Is there a standard way to wait any value change in volatile register model?
This would be like doing backdoor access `peek()` periodically through all volatile register until there is at least one value change.

```
// wait until DUT modifies any volatile register value.
my_reg_model.wait_volatile_reg_change();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to wait until the field value changes in the RTL and do something at that point in your TB?

Comment: @Tudor  Yes, for example I want to wait until certain status register value changes, then testbench can do some prediction to other register block, or do something else.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any infrastructure for that, unfortunately, as this would require some mechanism to wait on a change on a signal by specifying its hierarchical path as a string. You could probably do this using C/VPI code, but that's a bit more involved. A full answer is beyond the scope of this site.

There is a paper on the Verilab website that details how to do this: [I Spy with My VPI](http://www.verilab.com/files/snug_2012_paper71_final.pdf). I can't really find the C code for it though.

Comment: @AldoT I've updated the answer with a paper that could help you.